# How to make Auctex TeX-command-Show do nothing?

Tags: latex, auctex

When I use `C-a` to compile a source tex file, its final step is to call Evince to display the pdf (through `xdg-open`, I believe). However, in my computer this makes Emacs freeze for many seconds and finish with the following message:

```
LaTeX: successfully formatted {16} pages
error in process sentinel: dbus-call-method: D-Bus error: "Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"
error in process sentinel: D-Bus error: "Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"
Unable to load color "unspecified-fg"
```

I'd rather disable the call to Evince completely than bothering trying to fix this. And I don't want to abandon `C-a` in favor or `C-c` because then I'd have to type Return to compile.

How can I rebind `TeX-command-Show` to something that won't freeze Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AucTeX, the PDF viewer is specified via the variable `TeX-view-program-selection`. Find the entry for `output-pdf` and select a viewer you don't have. You'll get a small warning message in the mini-buffer, but otherwise you won't be interrupted. Alternatively, you could set the value to something you do have that isn't Evince, and you might solve your other problem.